# Should I use a WeakReference<Context> or Application Context in my AsyncTask?

Tags: android

I'm in a little bit of a dilemma and I hope you guys can help me with it.

As you can see I have an `AsyncTask` in which I have some code to save `Bitmap` objects as .jpg file to the gallery. In the `AsyncTask` I'm also using a `Context`, but as I understand using a context of an `Activity` in this inner class can cause memory leak, so I changed it to a `WeakReference<Context> weakContext;` so the garbage collector can collect it.

But by using the `Application` context that I get from the passed `View` from the constructor I should archive the same effect as the weak context reference

So is any better to use than the other in this case?

```
public class ViewToBitmap {

private View view;
private WeakReference<Context> weakContext;

public ViewToBitmap(@NonNull View view) {
    this.view = view;
}

 // This?
private WeakReference<Context> getContext() {
    weakContext = new WeakReference<>(view.getContext());
    return weakContext;
}

 // Or This?
private Context getContext() {
    return view.getContext().getApplicationContext();
}

private class AsyncSaveBitmap 
                extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
                implements MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      //TODO: Save bitmaps to gallery
      //CONTEXT IS USED HERE
       getContext().get()
       return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `View` object has explicit references to `Context` which was used upon view's inflation, you are effectively keeping a "transitive" hard reference to `Context` in instances of `ViewToBitmap` by keeping a hard reference to `View`.

Also, since `AsyncSaveBitmap` is not `static`, instance of this class has implicit reference to the enclosing instance of `ViewToBitmap`.

The net result is that as long as `AsyncSaveBitmap` exists, there is a chain of hard references to `Activity` that will prevent GC of that `Activity`.

So, the answer is: neither approach is good enough.

The best approach would be to refactor the logic in such a way that no long running code has references to `Context`, `Activity`, `View`, etc.

The most straightforward way of achieving this is to use Observer design pattern or Publish-Subscribe design pattern - this way you could "unregister" in life-cycle methods (e.g. `onStop()`), thus removing the potentially dangerous reference and preventing memory leaks.

**EDIT:**

For library purposes, where you don't necessarily need a specific `Context` and application's `Context` will suffice, the following patterns can be used (depending on whether your library exposed as Singleton or not):

```
// Use this approach if clients will use your library as Singleton
private static Context sAppContext;

public static void init(Context context) {
    sAppContext = context.getApplicationContext();
}

// Use this approach if clients will instantiate your library's object on each use
private final Context mAppContext;

public MyLibraryEntryClass(Context context) {
    mAppContext = context.getApplicationContext();
}
```

Comment: I will look into your suggestion. But what about passing the Context via an interface in the AsyncTask class? Or making it static and pass all the variables it needs via its constructor?

Comment: This code is actually a part of a library, so don't want users to bother with manually write extra code in onStop(). The only place I actually use context is only in one line `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{file.toString()}, null, this);` to scan saved bitmaps

Comment: @Muddz, if you write a library that requires `Context`, then a valid approach would be to use application's context. It can be obtained from any other `Context` by calling `getApplicationContext()`. Application's context can be treated as a Singleton, therefore there you can store it in a local variable without a risk of memory leak. This approach, however, should be used only as a last resort.

Comment: This seems to be the most simple and straigt forward approach. So in my library module I should make a class that extends Application and use that class' context right?¨

Comment: @Muddz, no. You should expose a method that accepts `Context` (e.g. `init(Context)` and unambiguously document that users must explicitly call `init(Context)` before they can start working with the library. That method will call `Context#getApplicationContext()` and store the obtained reference locally

Comment: Allright, but instead of a `init(Context context)` method I could just ask for it in my constructors of the library and then I make a `Context` member variable and assign the member variable to the passed context from the conustrctor like this: `context.getApplicationContext()`? If I'm completey wrong please provide me with an example

Comment: Thanks! I will edit the code in the library now. And I will also do favor to myself and read on the topics of memory leak in Android and the use of Context